# Outlook email move by sender

Tags: outlook

How can i create in outlook some quick action (shortcut or any) for moving email in folder by sender after reading and clicking or what?
For example:
emails:

- friend1@any.com
- friend2@any.com

Friend1s email, i have no task with it, than Ctrl + Shift + 2 and email moved to Friend1 folder. Friend2s email, i have no task with it, than Ctrl + Shift + 2 and email moved to Friend2 folder.

I tried categoryzing, but it work just client-side, and Quick action works with sender disregard.

THX for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop an add-in for Outlook which can do this for you. Depending on your requirements you may choose a VSTO or web based add-ins:

- VSTO: [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=Create%20the%20project,-To%20create%20a&text=On%20the%20File%20menu%2C%20point,Outlook%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project.)
- Web add-ins: [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator)

Quick steps are kept within Outlook profile. You may try to find the hidden folder called "Quick Step Settings" as described in the [Backing up and Restoring Quick Steps](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/backup-and-restore-quick-steps) article.